# Firebase get all data of nodes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have trouble to get datas from my node. I'm showing datas in listview.
[image: Firebase]

The top of the uid stars with "VVAA.." is my user's uid. I can reach datas of "34ern12" node. (Btw we don't define this node's name. Users do.) But I want to reach other node's datas. I mean I want to reach all datas of nodes of my useruid node. How I can do this? Do you have an idea?

Here is my code:

```
    firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    userId=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().toString();
    listview=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


   datareference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Arabalar").child(userId).child("34ern12");


    datareference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            list.add(value);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            list.remove(value);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),AracEkle.class));
        }
    });

    return view;

}}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "I want to reach all datas of nodes"? You want to display: `25yns1995` and `34ern12` and so on?

Comment: No I want to show 34ern12 and 25yns1995 node's datas(editTextEmisyonTarihi,editTextKaskoTarihi etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code:

```
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot != null) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if (map != null) {
                //Do everything you want
            }
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
datareference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The data you need is inside that `map` object. Hope it helps.